# Python async await on condition being true

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write an asynchronous method to run a query on hive (using pyhive). Now, pyhive does support asynchronous querying, I have no idea how to wait for the query to finish without blocking.

I can wait for the query to finish by repeatedly checking, but that's basically same as blocking.

```
def runQuery():
    cursor = hive.connect('localhost').cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from mytable', async_ = True)
    status = cursor.poll().operationState
    while status in (TOperationState.INITIALIZED_STATE, TOperationState.RUNNING_STATE):
        status = cursor.poll().operationState
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

So I use async, but then I don't know how to await. I tried the below code, but it throws `TypeError: object int can't be used in 'await' expression`

```
async def runQueryAsync():
    cursor = hive.connect('localhost').cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from mytable', async_ = True)
    #THIS DOESN'T WORK 
    await cursor.poll().operationState not in (TOperationState.INITIALIZED_STATE, TOperationState.RUNNING_STATE)
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

Any workarounds? Basically I want a way where instead of saying await methodCall, I say await until this condition is true

PS: To clarify, `cursor.execute('select * from mytable', async_ = True)` is not asynchronous in the python sense of returning a coroutine/future. It simply starts a query and immediately returns, and you have to check the state to know whether the query is finished. So `await cursor.execute('select * from mytable', async_ = True)` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to **actively await**:

```
async def runQueryAsync():
    cursor = hive.connect('localhost').cursor()
    await cursor.execute('select * from mytable', async_ = True)
    while cursor.poll().operationState not in (TOperationState.INITIALIZED_STATE, TOperationState.RUNNING_STATE):
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # try each 1 second
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

I'm not sure if you can `await cursor.execute('select * from mytable', async_ = True)`, but if not just use `cursor.execute('select * from mytable', async_ = True)` , altough it would make sense to use it there. If it works with `await` in the execute it you may not need to use the `while` loop, since it should continue when the execute is finished:

```
async def runQueryAsync():
    cursor = hive.connect('localhost').cursor()
    await cursor.execute('select * from mytable', async_ = True)
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Why re-execute the query every second? That's not the same as OP code where query is at most executed once

Comment: So is `asyncio.sleep` non-blocking as opposed to regular `time.sleep`?

Comment: @hoodakaushal, indeed, it is nonblocking. Usually you would want to use asyncio.sleep instead of time.sleep for corutines

Comment: using `sleep` in an async scheme is self defeating IMAO.  Might as well abandon asyncio if you do this.